# Ventless vs nonventless

Tags: vent, exhaust-fan

We are remodeling a bathroom. Currently it has an exhaust fan vented through the attic.

We purchased a Broan roomside series surface shield. (*No attic access required with ezduct connector, no attic access needed*).

Is this as efficient as what we already have?

Should we take this purchase back and stick with an attic vented exhaust?

Comment: "*Is this as efficient as what we already have?*"  We do not know what size/kind/model of fan you already have **and** a link to the new fan will give us some info on that. Hopefully your current fan is **NOT** vented into the attic and **IS** vent to the outside. It appears you MAY have a misconception about the new broan fan, it is ducted, just easy to connect to ducting.

Comment: What do you mean  "ventless"  ?  Is nonventless a word ?  **Please use the edit button to clarify what you are talking about and provide a very *detailed description* of both fans and the space involved**.

Comment: There are "ventless" exhaust fans for cooktops. They typically use activated charcoal to filter grease/fumes and return clean(ish) air to the kitchen. A bathroom fan is primarily for the humidity - no reasonably affordable filter can dehumidify the air, which is why they are *always* vented.

Comment: Than you for taking the time to try and help with my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code requires all bathrooms with bathing facilities to provide mechanical ventilation and it shall exhaust directly to the exterior. (See ICC M1506.4)

The capacity shall be 50 cfm intermittently and 20 cfm continuously. (See a ICC Table M1506.3)

Note: I remember the old code allowed an operable window in lieu of a mechanical vent.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try answer my question!

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can tell from the instructions I found ([HomeDepot](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/e3/e3119e11-e3cd-4d5f-ad76-f640ce70d742.pdf)), this van still vents to the outside. It seems that what they mean by "No attic access required with ezduct connector" is that when retrofitting/replacing another vent fan, you can connect up the existing ducting without accessing attic. If you were doing a new install, you'd still need to go into the attic to install the duct work.

This is an through-attic-vented fan.

Comment: After further investigation we found the same information that you found. Thank you for taking the time to help!